# WebLogic 10.3.2 LDAP Authentication failure after Domain Controller Patch MS14-066 (KB2992611)

Tags: ldap, domain-controller, weblogic, patch-management

I have configured a LDAP authenticator in my WebLogic 10.3.2 domain. Login worked until the domain controller was patched with MS14-066 (KB2992611). Domain Controller OS is Win Server2008R2 (x64).

The logfile after a restart of domain service looks like this:

<BEA-000000> <authenticate user:weblogic>
<BEA-000000> <new LDAP connection to host xxx.xxx.com port 636 use local connection is false>
<BEA-000000> <created new LDAP connection LDAPConnection { ldapVersion:2 bindDN:""}>
<BEA-000000> <connection failed netscape.ldap.LDAPException: Cipher not initialized (91)>
<BEA-000000>> <[Security:090294]could not get connection>

I hope, you can help
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't consider sniffing the traffic between the LDAP server and the WebLogic server. I suspect you're going to see [a failure similar to Google Chrome's failures of TLS 1.2 key exchange](https://serverfault.com/q/645054/7200).

You might try [removing the new cipher suites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb870930(v=vs.85).aspx) that MS14-066 adds to see if that changes the behavior. Microsoft has updated the MS14-066 patch to remove these cipher suites, as well, so you may want to consider removing the old patch and applying the new one.

Comment: Installing the updated MS14-066 patch solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: @user254673 Looks like you created a second account; you won't be able to accept the answer on this new one, which would mark it as the correct solution for anyone else who runs across this same problem.  See [here](http://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts) to get the accounts merged together.